# Is mapping features of strings helping parsing strings faster?

Tags: python, regex, string, dictionary

I am building a lexical dictionary that would help me look for English words according to phonetics and orthography. This dictionary will help me find specific examples of English words I need to teach kids.

For this I have made a large Python dictionary with about 200k word keys, of which the value is their phonetics.

To look up words, for instance, words with a final **-aK*e** grapheme, where K* would be any amount of consonants, I could parse all the keys with Regular Expressions.

However, I thought it would be a bit more clever to actually map words as if written in a grid. So I could "bookmark" all words whose final letter is a *-e* and so on. So when I look up words I could simply call on those bookmarks and be sure to have a hit and each time reduce the amount of words to parse as I go through multiple criteria search as with the example above.

Is my strategy really making sense? Or is using Regular Expression the way to go about it?

I have little time to program, I'd like some expert advice before I spend valuable time typing. Thanks.

Comment: What you're describing sounds quite a bit like a suffix tree (or trie), and it's a pretty standard way to do fast lookups from a large body of text given just a partial of the lookup value. I would imagine a regular expression (at least in the manner you are describing) would be quite slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that [`tries`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) make it very fast and efficient to answer these queries. It's a little unclear whether or not you'll always be searching from the end of the word or from the beginning, but if it's going to be a little bit of both then you'll have to build tries for both directions. And if ever you need to find matches in the middle, then neither trie would help.

Reverse indexes (like those that power search engines) sometimes get around this by storing words as character [n-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram), and then storing connectivity information between n-grams to construct words. For example, 'overflow' might be broken up as 'ove', 'rfl', and 'ow', and some metadata exists somewhere noting that there exists a word combining these three n-grams. Breaking up each word in different ways enables leading and trailing wildcard queries, though I'm fuzzy on the details :-/

**Or consider** the fact that unless performance is *really* critical for this application, that using regular expressions is probably fast enough (and could probably be optimized further) for this sort of dictionary size, and is very straightforward. A quick-and-dirty test using an 80k-word dictionary:

```
with open('dictionary.txt') as fin:
    words = fin.read().strip().split('\n')

import re
import time
expr = re.compile(r'a[^aeiouy]+e$', re.I)

# Of course, this extends easily to using a dictionary, too
def bench():
    start = -time.time()
    matches = [word for word in words if expr.search(word)]
    return start + time.time()
```

On my computer it's taking about 50ms, and for the simplicity and clarity of using regular expressions and your limited time, I think it's worth it.